# Does FastAPI websocket example deadlock the process?

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

The code in the docs has a `while True:` block and I am curious if something like that would deadlock the process. If I get two requests, would the second one just not go through? why or why not?

Source: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code sample given in your question, the short answer is that subsequent requests would go through (regardless of the `while True` loop) and processed concurrently.

The long answer is **depends** on what kind of operations you would like to perform inside the `async def` function/endpoint (including the `while True` loop), i.e., non-blocking I/O-bound or blocking I/O-bound or CPU-bound operations?. When a function is called with `await` and concerns a non-blocking [I/O-bound operation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#asynchronous-code) (e.g., *waiting* for data from the client to be sent through the network or *waiting* for contents of a file in the disk to be read), the `event loop` (that runs in the main thread) can then continue on and service other [coroutines](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#coroutines) (requests) while waiting for such operations to complete (i.e., in your case, *waiting* for a message to be either *received* or *sent*, using `await websocket.receive_text()` and  `await websocket.send_text()`). If, however, you perform some blocking I/O-bound tasks (e.g., using the `requests` library to perform HTTP requests) or [CPU-bound tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#is-concurrency-better-than-parallelism) (i.e., audio or image processing, machine learning, etc.), the `event loop` will get blocked; that means, no further requests would go through, until that I/O-bound or CPU-bound operation is complete.

Please refer to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details and solutions around this subject.